# Selecting element one element up of prev()

Tags: jquery

I am building twitter type app (web site) and I need a little help with jQuery selectors.

This is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="delete_box">
</div>

<div class="report_box">
</div>

<div class="twit">
  <a class="report_link">report</a>
  <a class="delete_link">delete</a>
</div>
```

The first two divs are pop ups for deleting and reporting a twit. And the third div is where the actual twit is. Both of the pop ups have their style set to display none. This structure is looped as long as their is twtis in th db.

This is the jQuery code that selects the pop up box that needs to show up.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_link', function()  {
    var op_twit = $(this).parents('.twit').prevAll('.delete_box');
    popup(op_twit);
});

$(document).on('click', '.report_link', function()  {
    var op_twit = $(this).parents('.twit').prevAll('.report_box');
    popup(op_twit);
});
```

Now the problem with this it selects all pop up boxes and shows them, if I do only prev() not prevAll() then only the report link works (because report_box is immediately before twit) and it works good because only one pop up is showing. But the delete link does not work when I place prev() for it.

So question is how can I select the previous element that is not exactly previous, but one up. I tried siblings() it`s the same problem as prevAll selects all the elements that have delete_box class.

Comment: Can't you rearrange your HTML into a more logical structure?

Comment: What about siblings('selector')? provided each of these sections are wrapped.

Comment: @PSL I tried siblings(".delete_box"), again it selects all divs with class report_box

Comment: aah ok so you have a flat html structure....

Comment: @VladimirSabo how about `$(this).closest('.twit').prevUntil('.twit').filter('.delete_box');` http://jsfiddle.net/dAUwL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
var op_twit = $(this).parents('.twit').prev().prev();
```

But I would suggest that you revisit your HTML structure.

**EDIT**

Since you have not included the HTML structure about how multiple tweets are in your HTML code, I am going to assume that they are siblings. So, as per my assumption your code would look something like this. Please correct me if my assumption is wrong.

```
<div class="delete_box"></div>
<div class="report_box"></div>
<div class="twit">
    <a class="report_link">report</a>
    <a class="delete_link">delete</a>
</div>

<div class="delete_box"></div>
<div class="report_box"></div>
<div class="twit">
    <a class="report_link">report</a>
    <a class="delete_link">delete</a>
</div>
```

You should have it something like. This would allow you to scope all your JS/CSS/jQuery to "tweet", thus making it easier and faster.

```
<div class="tweet">
    <div class="delete_box"></div>
    <div class="report_box"></div>

    <a class="report_link">report</a>
    <a class="delete_link">delete</a>
</div>
<div class="tweet">
    <div class="delete_box"></div>
    <div class="report_box"></div>

    <a class="report_link">report</a>
    <a class="delete_link">delete</a>
</div>
```

Additionally, I am not sure if you really need to have a separate delete/report div for each tweet. Again, as I do not know what the original requirement is, I am assuming that it is a confirmation overlay, which in my opinion can be reused.

Comment: Hm second comment about the structure. Can you explain what do you mean with that. How can I rearrange it? BTW this worked but it`s not very elegant. If nobody else comes up I will mark you answer as correct.

Comment: Although this works, it's completely dependent on an exact HTML structure which is sometimes hard to ensure (particularly for any future developers who may not know the requirement). It's better to refer to the class name, or better yet a unique ID.

Comment: @VladimirSabo - I have updated my answer to include more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `prevAll` and `last` :

```
var op_twit = $(this).closest('.twit').prevAll('.delete_box').first();
```

I changed also `parents` to `closest`, because I don't think you want to get all parents but only the first one.

Comment: Did not work, .last(); select the very last .delete_box. The pop ups are tied with the twit. Now when I try to delete the second twit (for example) the last twit on the page is deleted.

Comment: This solution seems like it should work.. Can you prepare a fiddle to show that this doesn't work...

Comment: Here's a fiddle that shows it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/srEDr/2/ The problem seems to be it always gets the first box in the DOM, not the one closest to the clicked element

Comment: @dystroy I believe you want `first`, not `last`. http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/srEDr/3/

Comment: @DACrosby I'd just fixed it (after I had seen your fiddle).

Answer (score 1):

A better HTML structure would be:

```
<div class="twit">
    <a class="report_link">Report</a>
    <a class="delete_link">Delete</a>

    <div class="delete_box">...</div>
    <div class="report_box">...</div>
</div>
```

Using this structure, you can climb the tree up to `.twit`, then look for the `.delete_box` or `.report_box` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you should revise your HTML structure a bit. The easiest way would be to add a holder div around each twit.

```
<div class="twit_hold">
    <div class="delete_box">Del Box</div>

    <div class="report_box">Rep Box</div>

    <div class="twit">
        <a href="#" class="report_link">report</a>
        <a href="#" class="delete_link">delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you simply refer to the anchor's parent `.twit_hold` and from there find the box you want to show. It is more up and down the DOM, but this way the order of your structure doesn't matter as much (you could have `twit, report_box, delete_box` or `report_box, delete_box, twit`  or any other arrangement.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_link', function()  {
    var t = $(this).parents('.twit_hold').find('.delete_box');
    // do stuff with the delete_box
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/srEDr/1/